# Sort a listbox after being dynamically allocated

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am pulling data in from a query, where three of the columns are being put into the same Listbox.  Does anyone know of a sort statement to sort it alphabetically after inserting the data into a listbox, or would I be better putting the results of my query into three arrays and then putting them the arrays in, in the order I want them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a listbox has the SORTED attribute, default FALSE. Make it true and the items are ordered on there contents

```
'l
    '
    Me.l.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.l.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(112, 163)
    Me.l.Name = "l"
    Me.l.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(211, 56)
    Me.l.Sorted = True
    Me.l.TabIndex = 1
```

where l is a ListBox

Comment: Can you do that to an asp:listbox?

Comment: As far as I know: no. Would this help you? I did not try it out, however http://forums.asp.net/p/1094374/1648309.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The example in msdn website should give you a better idea.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx

If this does not work, the other approach can be to attach your list box to a data view. Have that data view be attached to a data set. Put your data in the data set. Depending on the view order you can set the sort in the dataset.

Comment: I took a look at that earlier prior to posting this. That gets into sorting it by length rather that by letters or numbers, which is what I need.